# Double Payment in PayPal Subscriptions

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have a problem with PayPal recurring payment because my recurring payment is set in MONTHLY but after registration, I encounter double payment. The date of my registration is July 27, 2020, but instead of the next payment will be due next month PayPal. They charge me on the next day of my registration.

Please see the below image for the email from PayPal of my transaction today.

[image]

Comment: Where's the C# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set an "Every 1 month" cycle PayPal Subscription to bill immediately, the first payment will bill on the following day.

If you have a setup_fee, it will bill immediately at checkout time.

If both are happening, then you need to get rid of either the setup_fee, or the first cycle of billing.

The way you get rid of the first cycle of billing is to begin with a trial sequence of 1 month that is 1 cycle long (and has no charge)

Then, after the 1 month trial, the regular periods of billing every 1 month can begin.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a follow-up question, sir. Currently, I have a monthly recurring and I don't have a setup fee when is the first payment will be charge? The following day or next month? Thank you.

Comment: And also I set my Cycle into 0 because I have an infinite and regular type of subscription.

Comment: The next day, it runs in a batch.

Comment: Thank you so much @Preston PHX. I so much appreciate your answer.